# Warum der Konjunktiv II in »das wäre alles«?

Tags: phrase, subjunctive

Meine Deutschlehrerin sagt am Ende jedes Unterrichts:

> Das wäre alles für heute.

Warum kann man nicht einfach »Das ist alles« oder »Das war alles« sagen?

Auf Englisch sagt man »That’s all«. Hier gibt es keinen Konjunktiv. Warum benutzt man den Konjunktiv II auf Deutsch?

Comment: Willkommen auf German Language SE. Du darfst hier übrigens auch gerne auf Englisch fragen. Lass das Dich aber nicht davon abhalten, Dein Deutsch zu üben, indem du Fragen auf Deutsch stellst – zumal Du so eine kostenlose Korrektur bekommst.

Comment: Auch im Englischen sagt man: "That would be all".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wenn Deine Lehrerin »Das ist alles« oder »Das war alles« sagen würde, würde sie damit die Schüler vor vollendete Tatsachen stellen und keine Verlängerung des Unterrichts von Seiten der Schüler (z. B. durch Nachfragen) zulassen. Um dies zu vermeiden, nutzt sie den Konjunktiv II der Höflichkeit. Damit sagt sie gewissermaßen, dass sie den Unterricht beenden möchte (und es auch tut, wenn niemand Einspruch erhebt).

Von einem anderem Blickwinkel aus kann der Konjunktiv durch eine implizite hypothetische Bedingung erklärt werden:

> Das wäre alles für heute, wenn ihr keine Fragen o. Ä. mehr hättet.

Dass hier der Konjunktiv II genutzt wird, obwohl die Bedingung gar nicht irreal ist, ist wieder ein Ausdruck der Höflichkeit und lädt die Schüler gewissermaßen dazu ein, Fragen o. Ä. zu stellen.

Wenn man nun umgekehrt eine Veranstaltung unwiderruflich beenden möchte, kann man dies durch »Das ist alles« oder »Das war alles« ausdrücken (beide Zeiten sind gleichermaßen in Ordnung).

Comment: Ich finde zwar auch, dass der Indikativ hier etwas brüsk klingen könnte, denke aber nicht, dass das hier das wesentliche ist.  Ich kann zum Beispiel auch nach getaner Arbeit zufrieden "Damit wäre das erledigt!" sagen.

Comment: @Carsten S, außer dein Chef kommt dann und bittet dich noch kurz xy zu tun. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Ich hatte mir in einem anderen Zusammenhang darum Gedanken gemacht. Zunächst hatte ich mich nach ähnlichen Fällen umgesehen. Neben '*das wär's*' habe ich bis jetzt gefunden:

1. Das wäre von meiner Seite erst einmal alles.
2. Das hätten wir / Das hätten wir geschafft.
3. [*am Ende einer Fahrt*]  Da wären wir.
4. [*bei einer Wohnungsbegehung*]  Und hier wäre dann das Kinderzimmer / Und hier hätten wir das Kinderzimmer.
5. Wir kämen jetzt zum nächsten Punkt der Tagesordnung.

Auffällig ist, dass alle diese Äußerungen das Ende einer Situation bzw. den Übergang in eine andere Situation kennzeichnen. Genau dies haben zwei Autorinnen zum Anlass genommen, diese Art von Konjunktiven als ["**Scharnier-Konjunktive**"](https://books.google.de/books?id=AFUcbDP8kbEC&pg=PA843&lpg=PA843&dq=da%20w%C3%A4ren%20wir%20warum%20konjunktiv&source=bl&ots=6lrvpuIPTx&sig=ACfU3U0UUF29wLa3CGCuVe-eVMgR_w425A&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizg4zi9srpAhVbwAIHHQo_DJsQ6AEwAnoECFwQAQ#v=onepage&q=da%20w%C3%A4ren%20wir%20warum%20konjunktiv&f=false) zu bezeichnen*. Man **kann** diese Konjunktive als Ableger von Höflichkeits-Konjunktiven mit einem nicht ausgeführten *wenn*-Satz interpretieren, wie Wrzlprmft das getan hat, die Frage bleibt, wie überzeugend das letztlich ist. Denn es liegt nicht unmittelbar auf der Hand, warum jeder, der mit '*das wär's*' einen Schlusspunkt setzt, immer noch Gelegenheit zu Rückfragen geben will. Er würde etwa auch sagen können

> Das wär's wieder mal, meine Damen und Herren. Entschuldigen Sie meinen plötzlichen Aufbruch, ich muss leider gleich weiter, wir sehen uns dann nächste Woche, gleiche Zeit, gleicher Ort.

Ebensowenig würde mir einleuchten, unter welchen Vorbehalt man nach erledigtem Auftrag (z.B. Umzugshilfe) seinen Kommentar

> Das hätten wir, wir können jetzt abrücken.

stellen wollte. Etwa: "*Falls nicht noch was anderes ist...*"? Etwas Ähnliches ließe sich praktisch immer sagen. Nehmen wir die Brötchentheke:

> Und außerdem? - *Danke, das wär's. Außer mir fällt noch etwas anderes ein*.

Als kleiner Scherz am Rande wäre das durchaus denkbar, aber nicht als ernst gemeinte Aufforderung an die Verkäuferin, noch ein wenig zu warten, ob der Bestellvorgang wirklich abgeschlossen ist.

Die beiden Autorinnen Ursula Bredel und Cäcilia Töpler stellen zu diesem Thema fest, dass derartige Konjunktive an "Handlungsübergängen" sich finden. Scharnier-Konjunktive würden verwendet, "wenn der Sprecher davon ausgeht (...), dass das betreffende Ereignis dem Hörer nicht bekannt / so nicht bekannt war":

- Die Brötchenverkäuferin weiß nicht, ob der Kunde mit seiner Bestellung fertig ist.
- Die Sprachkurs-Lerner wissen nicht zu 100% genau, wann der letzte Satz an diesem Kurstag gesagt sein soll; auch nicht bei einer Klausur oder Prüfung, wo sie mit diesem Satz zur Abgabe der Prüfungsunterlagen aufgefordert werden.
- Der Fahrer, der eine Kollegin bei sich zu Hause absetzen will, weiß nicht, wann dieses Zuhause erreicht ist - oder umgekehrt: Die Fahrgäste, die dem Gepäck nach zu schließen neu in der Stadt sind, wissen nicht, ob sie an ihrem Hotel angekommen sind oder ob der Fahrer einfach mal anhalten will, bis er sein '*Da wären wir*' sagt.
- Die Kaufinteressenten, die vom Immobilienmakler durch den Rohbau geführt werden, wissen nicht, wie der Architekt sich die Raumaufteilung gedacht hatte; jedoch auch seinen Freunden bei einer Einweihungsparty würde man jeden Raum mit seiner Funktionsbezeichnung im Konjunktiv II vorstellen können: *Und hier wäre noch der Arbeitsraum von Peter*, was man doch eigentlich sieht. Sie erfahren jedoch neu, dass auch dieser Raum in die Besichtigung einbezogen ist.
- Die Anwesenden bei einer Versammlung wissen nicht, wann der Versammlungsleiter einen bestimmten Punkt als abschließend behandelt verstanden wissen und zum nächsten Punkt auf der Liste übergehen will.

In den hier vorgestellten Fällen ist immer klar, was als nächstes kommen soll, nur nicht, wann genau das sein wird. Mit den Konjunktiv-Sätzen werden die jeweiligen Hörer in ihrem Bewusstsein aus der Situation davor herausgeholt und auf die nächste Situation hin orientiert: Der Kunde war beim Bestellen, jetzt wäre er damit fertig, dann stelle ich mich aufs Bezahlen ein; es sieht so aus, als wenn der Dozent zum Ende kommen will, tatsächlich, jetzt hat er gesagt, das wär's für heute gewesen, da kann ich jetzt meine Sachen einpacken; ... und in der Wohnung: Das ist mir eigentlich ein bisschen zu schnell, ich hab mir das Badezimmer noch gar nicht richtig angesehen, das fand ich interessant, aber jetzt sind wir schon wieder beim nächsten...

Es ist das Umschlagen einer Situation in die nächste, auf dessen Scheitelpunkt der Konjunktiv den inneren Zeiger des Hörers auf einen imaginären inneren Ort stellt, der bereits nicht mehr in der alten Situation liegt, doch auch noch nicht vollwertig **in** der neuen Situation anzusiedeln ist, sondern: Man steht noch **vor** dem Neuen und orientiert sich neu. Das hat eine gewisse Ähnlichkeit mit manchen Arten von Höflichkeits-Konjunktiven (*wenn Sie vielleicht hier mal schauen würden*), *würde*-Formen sind beim Scharnier-Konjunktiv jedoch ausgeschlossen.

Übrigens kann ich ein *Das wär's* auch zu mir selber sagen, vielleicht sogar sehr entschieden als *Das wär's jetzt aber wirklich!* Und dies, obwohl ich doch eigentlich wissen sollte, wann ich Schluss machen will!? Es geht jedoch nicht um dieses Wollen, der eigentliche Mechanismus dieser Konjunktive operiert im Bewusstsein des Hörer, in diesem Fall in meinem Bewusstsein: Ich muss mich auf das Beenden der aktuellen Situation auch tatsächlich einstellen, und um diesen Einstellungs- und Perspektivwechsel, um die innere Neuausrichtung aufs Nächste und das Loslassen des Alten geht es. Es fällt mir möglicherweise schwer, aufzuhören, weil ich fertig werden will, aber irgendwann siegt die Vernunft und ich mache mir bewusst, dass es wirklich an der Zeit ist, für heute endlich Feierabend zu machen - morgen wär' ja auch noch ein Tag!

Answer (score 1):

Die Frage ist berechtigt. Und momentan muß ich sagen, habe ich keine Antwort parat. Ich kann nur eine Vermutung äußern. Vielleicht ist das nur ein Teil einer längeren Formel, etwa:

Das wäre alles für heute, es sei denn, es hat noch jemand eine Frage/ es sei denn, es gibt noch Fragen.